# Can't Detect PC Drives While Installing Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I have an old netbook lying around, I installed Windows 7 two days ago, and it worked great. I decided I need to install Windows XP.

During the process, it showed me that Windows XP can't be installed since it didn't detect a valid Windows NT to upgrade it. I improvised and deleted all partitions by using GParted (thinking that Windows 7 was causing the problem because it can't downgrade that as an "upgrade"), so now all partitions (except "system reserved") are unallocated, I re-entered the setup and went through all the way up until I need to choose the destination Drive of the installation, there I found it doesn't recognize ANY HDD drives, only the USB I'm booting from.

I rebooted again into GParted and made a partition (NTFS - 50GB) and saved the work. Booted the WinXP setup and same thing, can't detect anything but the USB device. I've actually repartitioned all Drives (except the one that says "system reserved" and it's about 100MB) and still nothing is showing in my WinXP Setup. Any suggestions?

Comment: is the hard drive sata?

Comment: Check BIOS AHCI options for disk controller. Older operating systems can have problems With some newer hardware, especially sata drives, with AHCI enabled.

Comment: I don't understand what these particular things mean but my BIOS says "ATA/IDE configuration: (enabled/disabled/[enhanced])
then under it "configure SATA as (IDE/[ACHI]). Between the [ ] means that's what's chosen.

Comment: Try selecting IDE and reboot to O.S. setup

Comment: Did so already, testing now.

Comment: @The_aLiEn, great it worked. Thanks, add your answer please so I can accept it. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Not at all. Glad it is fixed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check BIOS `AHCI` options for disk controllers. Older operating systems can have problems With some newer hardware, especially SATA drives, with AHCI enabled. Disabling AHCI, or setting configuration to IDE forces BIOS to communicate with a legacy perspective.

Try selecting IDE and reboot to O.S. setup.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the system reserve, it will probably be GPT partition which xp can not read.

Comment: Will do now. I'll report back

Comment: Still the same problem.
Only detecting the USB device.

Comment: The harddisk is empty? no partitions at all showing on gparted? you did apply the operation on gparted? Did the netbook have XP on it previous and how old is it?

Comment: GParted shows all drives, I did apply changes, the Netbook is fairly capable although I don't remember what I shipped with but I do know it ran Window 7 seamlessly for all its age up until now. (Thought: I'm now going see if Windows 7 recognizes the Drives.)

Comment: If 7 recognises the drive it might be drivers and you need to supply the drier to XP to detect it

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP did not have built in drivers for sata controllers. You may have to manually slipstream the drivers using a software like nlite and use the modified CD to format the PC

Comment: Thanks for the input, selecting IDE helped and I already have made the modified USB (or so I think, since it's different than the things I used to do with Win7). Thanks.